# Is the khtml prefix necessary?

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

Should I feel bad about leaving out the `-khtml-` prefix from css attributes like `border-radius` and `box-shadow`?

What is the percentage of Konqueror users anyway?

Comment: Hard to say, it's usually just in the "other" listing on statistics sites...

Comment: Even recent versions of Konqueror don't need that prefix anymore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the browser does not even show in your stats and your "other" browser listing isn't 30% or something significant, I think you can safely leave it out.

(And "other" is so low on StatsCounter that it barely registers. http://gs.statcounter.com/)

Comment: IMO, folks using really niche browsers should be used to not getting a full experience.

Comment: Agreed! @Wesley Murch  It's like those on 2002 mobile flip phone expecting an iPhone browsing experience. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this makes me fill a little better. I was supprised at how small the "other" category was on StatCounter`s statistics! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 3):

**Necessity of khtml**

> Basically khtml is a prefix for the Konqueror browser

But now days, it is not required to the use of this prefix, because the Konqueror latest browsers understand the the css

> for e.g. -khtml-property_name: value